# Problem bounding some integral

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I've been trying to bound the following integral:

$|\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} sin(ks-kt)f'(t)dt|$ knowing that $f(t)$ is a $2\pi$-periodic function.

The idea is is to bound it in a way that that does not depend of s. I tried calculating it but I got nowhere.

Thanks so much for your answers!

PD: This problem appeared to me while trying to prove some Fourier series properties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can bound it by $\int_{-\pi}^\pi |f'(t)|dt$.

Comment: even if sin(ks-kt) is not always positive in that interval?

Comment: Yes. Use the inequality $|\int f| \le \int |f|$.

Comment: So, If I had $cos(ks-kt)f'(t)$ instead' of $sin(ks-kt)f(t)$ I would be able to bound it just the same way right? :)

Comment: Yes, you would.